# GCP BigQuery - Transaction is aborted due to concurrent update (though no concurrent update)

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have something like this:

```
BEGIN transaction ;
    
    
    UPDATE `$BQ_DATA_PROJECT`.`$DWDB`.Table_a AS ic ;
    
     update `$BQ_DATA_PROJECT`.`$DWDB`.Table_a AS ic ;
    
     Insert into `$BQ_DATA_PROJECT`.`$DWDB`.Table_a ;
    
     Commit transaction;
```

Error:

Transaction is aborted due to concurrent update against table

```
  `$BQ_DATA_PROJECT`.`$DWDB`.Table_a
```

The GCP big query documentation says we can have 20 DML operations for a table but it fails just for this.

And this is random, sometimes it fails, sometimes it doesn't. If I run after sometime it succeeds.

One thing that works is not giving them in a BT/CT block but Is there anything else that I can try to avoid getting
the concurrent update error

Comment: If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to concurrency of mutating DML (UPDATE, DELETE and MERGE) statements which possibly causes conflict as whenever a [transaction mutates](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions#transaction_concurrency) (update or deletes) rows in a table, then other transactions or DML statements that mutate rows in the same table cannot run concurrently. Conflicting transactions are canceled. As BigQuery uses [optimistic concurrency control](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dml-without-limits-now-in-bigquery) means when committing a job, BigQuery checks if mutations generated by the job conflict with any other mutations performed on the table while the job runs and if any conflict is found then commit operation is aborted.

To avoid this error, I would suggest space out the DML operations such that they operate on the same table but at different times. If your application is more transaction specific then it would be better to use Cloud SQL rather than Bigquery. You can follow the [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#best_practices) to avoid any errors in future.